# Why the algorithm end after the first condition?

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

I'm designing a number guessing algorithm for use as a game.

Can anyone suggest why does the algorithm end after the first condition?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int num = 5;
int guess;

cout << "Guess a number \n";
cin >> guess;


if (guess==num)
{
    cout << "You guessed the correct number \n";
}
else if (guess < num)
{
    cout << "Your guess is lower than the number \n";
    cout << "Guess again \n";
    cin >> guess;
}
else
{
    cout << "Your guess is higher than the number \n";
    cout << "Guess again \n";
    cin >> guess;
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: @user3528438  not sure how to do it but i am sure i will find something online thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of loop if you want that the algorithm would be repeated.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 5;
    int guess;

    cout << "Guess a number \n";

    do
    {
        cin >> guess;

        if ( guess == num )
        {
            cout << "You guessed the correct number \n";
        }
        else if ( guess < num )
        {
            cout << "Your guess is lower than the number \n";
            cout << "Guess again \n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Your guess is higher than the number \n";
            cout << "Guess again \n";
        }

    } while ( guess != num );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to guess again I'd recommend a loop. Otherwise your code works as intended.

```
while(number != guess)
        {
            if(number * 2 < guess){
                cout << "Way to high. Try again." << endl;
                cin >> guess;
            }

            if(number / 2 > guess)
            {
                cout << "Tip : My number is NOT low. Try again." << endl;
                cin >> guess;
            }

            if(number < guess)
            {
                cout << "To high try something lower. Feed me a number." << endl;
                cin >> guess;
            }
            if(number > guess)
                cout << "To low, try again." << endl;
                cin >> guess;
        }
```